# Showing that a function very close to the identity map is indeed bijection

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I managed to show that $f$ is injective. However, without the assumption that $f$ is continuously differentiable, I have trouble showing that $f$ is surjective. Could anyone please come up with an ingenious idea about showing that $f$ is indeed surjective?